# converting three data columns into three rows with one column

Tags: excel, formula

I have a set of data that is as follows

```
   _A_  _B__  __C__  ___D___  _E_  ____F_____
1  Jan  2014  apple  5 units  $10  $1.25 cost
2  Feb  2014  apple  7 units  $14  $1.75 cost
```

I want to create a graph that can filter using slicers off of the values (ie units or $s). I know the data has to appear like the following but can't figure out how to manipulate.

```
   _A_  _B__  __C__  ___D___   __E___
1  jan  2014  apple  units       5.00
2  jan  2014  apple  $ volume   10.00
3  jan  2014  apple  cost        1.25
4  feb  2014  apple  units       7.00
5  feb  2014  apple  $ volume   14.00
6  feb  2014  apple  cost        1.75
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the following macro to a button on the sheet where the top set of data is located. Clicking on the button (once macro is assigned) will convert to bottom row. Any issues, please respond.

```
Sub SortData()
    ' Assign the following macro to a button or shape to achieve your result
    Dim StartingSheet, val As String
    StartingSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    With Sheets.Add
        For i = 1 To Sheets(StartingSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 1 To 3
                .Cells(((i - 1) * 3 + (j Mod 3) + 1), 1).Value = Sheets(StartingSheet).Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Cells(((i - 1) * 3 + (j Mod 3) + 1), 2).Value = Sheets(StartingSheet).Cells(i, 2).Value
                .Cells(((i - 1) * 3 + (j Mod 3) + 1), 3).Value = Sheets(StartingSheet).Cells(i, 3).Value
                If j = 1 Then
                    val = "$ volume"
                    .Cells(((i - 1) * 3 + (j Mod 3) + 1), 5).Value = Replace(Sheets(StartingSheet).Cells(i, 5).Value, "$", "")
                End If
                If j = 2 Then
                    val = "cost"
                    .Cells(((i - 1) * 3 + (j Mod 3) + 1), 5).Value = Replace(Replace(Sheets(StartingSheet).Cells(i, 6).Value, "$", ""), " cost", "")
                End If
                If j = 3 Then
                    val = "units"
                    .Cells(((i - 1) * 3 + (j Mod 3) + 1), 5).Value = Replace(Sheets(StartingSheet).Cells(i, 4).Value, " units", "")
                End If
                .Cells(((i - 1) * 3 + (j Mod 3) + 1), 4).Value = val
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```